# Changes in pitch when playing vinyl on relatively new turntable

Tags: vinyl

Recently I bought a new turntable, TTUSB Numark, and I just started to notice that there are some pitch changes when I play records. I believe that this was initially not the case.

At first I thought that it might be the vinyl record itself, but after trying different vinyls I noticed that the problem is not record specific. Moreover, the random pitch change on a certain record is not specific to a certain place/time in the record. I can't re-produce the problem so to say at, for example, time 1:33 of record X. Also, it is not a continuous problem, but seems to happen approximately 2 a 3 times per side, and I can hear the pitch change for something between 2-8 seconds.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this, and if yes, how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe an occasional wobble in the speed of the motor ? With suitable equipment you might be able to pin it down, but you could maybe do a timed video, with a mark on the turntable so you know when 1 rotation is complete, and slow down the video on playback to see if there is occasional variation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the belt is either loose or some particles may have gotten in there.

I would take off the platter and observe the belt. If it is loose and the belt is not defective, then you can adjust the tightness by turning the adjustment screw to the right to tighten and left to loosen.

If it seems like it may be be dirty, I would get yourself a can of compressed air and blow around the belt and platter.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, as you said I took off the platter and inspected the belt, but all seems fine. No particles/dust, and I don't think that it is too loose. 

When you say that I could adjust the tightness by turning the adjustment screws in case the belt is loose (which doesn't seem to be the case), what do you exactly mean? When I take off my platter I see three screws, but they don't affect the tightness of the belt

Answer (score 1):

an expensive potential solution is get a direct drive turntable so you don't have to deal with the belt. My Technics SL1200 is wonderful in terms of stability in speed.